# Db connection not being closed

Tags: php, postgresql, php-pgsql

I've just opened submitted a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75419) relating to postgres **database connections not been closed/cleaned** by the garbage collector in any **php 7.X** version for the below scenario, I was hoping if someone could provide some insight on why such a behavior & point any *.ini* settings that could help avoid this.

```
<?php 
$dbLink1 = pg_connect( "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=development", PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW );
pg_query($dbLink1, 'select 1; /*FIRST*/');

$dbLink2 = pg_connect( "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=development", PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW );
pg_query($dbLink2, 'select 1; /*SECOND*/');

/*closing first link*/
pg_close($dbLink1);

$dbLink2 = pg_connect( "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=development", PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW );
pg_query($dbLink2, 'select 1; /*THIRD*/');

/*2nd 3rd connection remain idle on the database connection as long as the scripts is alive, the 2nd connection overridden by $dbLink2 should be automatically destroyed*/

sleep(200); ?>
```

On PHP 5.6, 5.5 I'm noticing all unused connections are automatically cleaned up and I'm left with just 1 idle connection on the database, which doesn't seem to be the case in PHP 7.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.configuration.php#ini.pgsql.auto-reset-persistent possibly?

Comment: Not using persistent connections tough

Comment: If you can show that it only happens in php7 then I'd suspect it's a php7 bug. Any luck looking through PHP's bug db https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: @ScottMarlowe Yes, I reported one bug & this shall be fixed in a future release

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug in PHP7 and shall be fixed in a future release.

Details: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75419

Fix Commit: https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a645af44561acb4696bc9b98a656781ded81fb79